# How to access a class if you have a string of its name in javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, class, web-component, custom-element

In javascript, if I have 2 strings `myApp` and `my-app` and was told that `myApp` is really a name of a class that extends `HTMLElement`, and `my-app` is that class's tagname, how can I use JavaScript to verify that (assuming that the class is already defined)?

Basically the test should pass if this was really defined already

```
class myApp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

customElements.define('my-app', myApp);
```

Basically, it needs to check that `myApp` is a class and does extend `HTMLElement` (though it's possible it may extend something else, such as `Polymer.Element`, and on wards, but eventually, it must extend `HTMLElement`).

And then secondly, it must check `my-app` is the tag name of that class.

How can this be done in javascript?

I tried `eval("myApp")` but it did not work.

Comment: for the first part, `myApp.prototype instanceof HTMLElement` should return true if myApp has HTMLElement in its ancestry

Comment: I'm not 100% sure if Polymer.Element extends HTMLElement, so I could probably do `myApp.prototype instanceof HTMLElement || myApp.prototype instanceof Polymer.Element`. But the other parts I have no clue.

Comment: I tried `Polymer.Element instanceof HTMLElement` and that was false apparently.

Comment: if myApp extends Polymer.Element extends HTMLElement, then HTMLElement is still an ancestor of myApp ... instanceof doesn't check one level of ancestry :p

Comment: `I tried` - just do what I suggested instead

Comment: I tried this `Polymer.Element instanceof HTMLElement` and it was `false`, so I have to check each individually, which is fine still

Comment: I didn't say to try that, did I? it'd be `Polymer.Element.prototype` anyway - but that has nothing to do with the question

Comment: oh right, so polymer.element does extend htmlelement.

Comment: no idea, it's your code :p

Comment: "downvote" description? If you are going to serial "downvote" you may as well leave your reason therefor as well. Since you evidently have a rational  reason for your actions why keep the reason to yourself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `customElements.get()` to get the custom element class from its tag name.

```js
class myApp extends HTMLElement {
  constructor() {
    super()
  }
}
customElements.define( 'my-app', myApp )

console.log( customElements.get( 'my-app' ) === myApp )  //true
```

Answer (score 1):

To check if the `class` exists and `extends` `HTMLElement` the check should be performed in the same scope as the `class` is declared by trying to declare `myApp` using `const` which should throw a `SyntaxError`  or using `console.assert()`.

Once first part is verified you can create the element and check the `.is` property or `.tagName` of the created element.

```js
class myApp extends HTMLElement {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }
}

customElements.define('my-app', myApp); 

// string
let str = "myApp";
// get the object, if the object exists
const myApp_ = new Function(`return ${str}`)();
// check if `myApp` exists
console.assert(myApp_ === void 0
, myApp_
, [`${myApp_} is defined`
  , new RegExp(`${str} extends HTMLElement`).test(`${myApp_}`)]);
```

Comment: The problem here is that you don't have a reference to the class name `myApp`. You just have the string "myApp" and "my-app".

Comment: @omega That is not a "problem". It would be a problem if you did not have the strings. Pass the presumptive `class` identifier as string as the identifier to `console.assert()` to get a `Boolean` evaluation and pass the string as identifier as second parameter to get string representation of `class`

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, can you show an example? Your code above uses a variable name and not a string "myApp" and "my-app".

Comment: @omega _"I'm not sure I follow, can you show an example?"_ See stacksnippets. _"Your code above uses a variable name and not a string "myApp" and "my-app"."_ Yes, once you have the string pass the string as an identifier to `console.assert()`

Comment: @omega The stacksnippets at the present Answer

Comment: sry, I'm still pretty lost lol. How do I pass the string into console.assert?

Comment: @omega You do not pass the string to `console.assert()`. Once you have the string you pass the object reference having same characters as string to `console.assert()`

Comment: But the primary thing I don't know how to do is how to get the object reference from the string itself.

Comment: Not sure what you mean? The string contains the exact same characters as the presumptive object. Pass the reference as an identifier to `console.assert()`. Alternatively `const myApp = void 0`, which should also throw an error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Identifier 'myApp' has already been declared`

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood the main question. The question is, how do I first get the reference to the class object, if I only have the string of it's name. Once I have the object, then I can probably check it's prototype to see if its instance of htmlelement, and then do .gettagname to check the last part.

Comment: _"I only have the string of it's name"_ That is the object reference as a string. Pass the literal reference to `console.assert()` or try to declare again using `const`. `class` and `const` are not stored as properties of the global object, it is not possible to get expected result with `window[className]`

Comment: it's still confusing, are you saying I do console.assert("myApp")? if not, can you show with code please? Note, I don't have a literal reference in my code, I only have a string of the variable name literally.

Comment: @omega The code is at stacksnippets. No, you do not pass the string, you pass the object reference that you get from the string `console.assert(myApp === void 0, myApp, ["myApp is defined"])`, else it is not possible to query for unknown `const` or `let` or `class` variables at the global object using bracket notation as the declarations are not set as properties of the global object. Also, the same scope is necessary. The same `const` or `class` identifiers can be declared again within `try..catch`` within error being thrown

Comment: I saw that code, but what you are doing is assuming you already have the object reference, since you are putting that in console.assert(). But when you say `object reference that you get from the string`. I have no idea what you mean by that. How can you just get that from a string, Do you mean with `eval()`?

Comment: what is the regular expression check for?

Comment: To check for `"myApp extends HTMLElement"` at `myApp.toString()`, which template literal  `${myApp_}` ultimate returns

Comment: isn't it enough to do `myApp_.prototype instanceof HTMLElement` ?

Comment: @omega Yes. There are various methods of determining the result

Answer (score 1):

Ok I figured it out, I can just do

```
    var worked = false;
    var claimedClassName = 'myApp';
    var claimedElementName = 'my-app'; 

    try {
        const r = new Function(`return ${claimedClassName}`)();
        if (!(r.prototype instanceof HTMLElement)) {
            throw new Error('Class is not instance of HTMLElement');
        }
        var a = new r();
        if (a.tagName.toLowerCase() != claimedElementName.toLowerCase()) {
            throw new Error('Tagname does not match');
        }
        worked = true;
    } catch (err) {
        alert(err.message + "\n" + err.stack);
    }

    if (worked) alert("pass!")
    else alert("fail!");
```

Comment: If your Answer resolves Question you can accept your own Answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Your function version is probably better. I will accept yours instead.

Comment: I implemented custom elements in Chrome and I think your code has a problem. IIRC tag names are ASCII-lowercased, but you use toLowerCase which I think also lowercases non-ASCII. customElements.get is simple and direct--use that.